# Поиск минимального пути в графе с окрашенными рёбрами

Tags: алгоритм, графы, поиск-пути

> Задан неориентированный граф с N вершинами и M рёбрами. Вершины пронумерованы, начиная с единицы. Каждое ребро характеризуется своим весом и цветом (красным либо чёрным). Вам необходимо найти путь с минимальным суммарным весом из вершины 1 в вершину N. При этом путь должен проходить вперемежку по красным и чёрным рёбрам. Это означает, что если первое ребро в найденном пути — красное, то второе должно быть чёрным, третье — опять красным, и т.д. Если же первое ребро — чёрное, то второе должно быть красным, и т.д.

Пробовал, решал и получился кое-какой алгоритм, но он не всегда работает корректно. Возможно у кого-то будут идеи?

Пробовал алгоритм Дейкстры. При этом сохранял для каждой вершины цвет того ребра,по которому попал в эту вершину и потом если в данную вершину можно попасть по красному и чёрному ребру,то я эту вершину 2 раза проверял. И затем просто перебирал подряд все вершины в которые можно из неё попасть и так для каждой.

Не получилось что конкретно не знаю. Так как в моём случае проверка идёт след.образом:есть 27 тестов(какие они я не вижу). И вот у меня проходит 20/27. Ошибки в коде не могу найти
вот собственно сам код

```
    versh.push(0);
reddist[0] = 0;
blackdist[0] = 0;
while (!versh.empty())
{
    int temp;
    temp = versh.front();
    versh.pop();
    for (int l = 0; l < N; l++)
    {
        int m = 1;
        if (ves[temp][l] >= 0)
        {
            if (temp != 0)
            {
                if (redcolor[temp] != -1)
                {
                    if (cvet[temp][l] != 0)
                    {
                        blackcolor[l] = cvet[temp][l];
                        m = 2;
                    }
                }//цвет вершины в которую пришёл по чёрному чёрный
                if (blackcolor[temp] != -1)
                {
                    if (cvet[temp][l] != 1)
                    {
                        redcolor[l] = cvet[temp][l];
                        m = 3;
                    }
                }//аналогично только красный
            }
            else
            {
                if (cvet[temp][l] == 0)
                {
                    redcolor[l] = 0;
                    m = 3;
                }
                else
                {
                    blackcolor[l] = 1;
                    m = 2;
                }
            }
            if (redcolor[l] != -1 && m == 3)
            {
                if (reddist[l] > blackdist[temp] + ves[temp][l])
                {
                    reddist[l] = blackdist[temp] + ves[temp][l];
                    versh.push(l);
                    if (l == N - 1)
                    {
                        if (res > reddist[l])
                            res = reddist[l];
                    }
                }
            }
            if (blackcolor[l] != -1 && m == 2)
            {
                if (blackdist[l] > reddist[temp] + ves[temp][l])
                {
                    blackdist[l] = reddist[temp] + ves[temp][l];
                    versh.push(l);
                    if (l == N - 1)
                    {
                        if (res > blackdist[l])
                            res = blackdist[l];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        m = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос - какой алгоритм вы пробовали, что у вас не получилось?

Comment: Известная задача - динамическое программирование - в чем проблема?

Comment: "Не получилось что конкретно не знаю." - если даже вы не знаете, то как нам знать?

Comment: Так возможно подскажите какое-либо решение. Как лучше тот же алгоритм Дейкстры реализовать для данной задачи

Comment: @Артём дополнил ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение оказалось простым. Оказывается в данном случае обязательно нужно учесть,что у нас мультиграф и есть петли. Вот собственно и части кода
   Вот так мы считываем:

```
    while (fin >> i)
    {
        info.push_back(i);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < info.size(); j++)
    {
        if (j % 4 == 2)
        {
            if (ves[info[j - 2] - 1][info[j - 1] - 1] == -1)
            {
                ves[info[j - 2] - 1][info[j - 1] - 1] = info[j];
                ves[info[j - 1] - 1][info[j - 2] - 1] = info[j];
                cvet[info[j - 2] - 1][info[j - 1] - 1] = info[j + 1];
                cvet[info[j - 1] - 1][info[j - 2] - 1] = info[j + 1];
            }
            else
            {
                if (cvet[info[j - 2] - 1][info[j - 1] - 1] != info[j + 1])
                {
                    if (tves[info[j - 2] - 1][info[j - 1] - 1] == -1)
                    {
                        tves[info[j - 2] - 1][info[j - 1] - 1] = info[j];
                        tves[info[j - 1] - 1][info[j - 2] - 1] = info[j];
                        tcvet[info[j - 2] - 1][info[j - 1] - 1] = info[j + 1];
                        tcvet[info[j - 1] - 1][info[j - 2] - 1] = info[j + 1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (tves[info[j - 2] - 1][info[j - 1] - 1] > info[j])
                        {
                            tves[info[j - 2] - 1][info[j - 1] - 1] = info[j];
                            tves[info[j - 1] - 1][info[j - 2] - 1] = info[j];
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (cvet[info[j - 2] - 1][info[j - 1] - 1] == info[j + 1])
                {
                    if (ves[info[j - 2] - 1][info[j - 1] - 1] > info[j])
                    {
                        ves[info[j - 2] - 1][info[j - 1] - 1] = info[j];
                        ves[info[j - 1] - 1][info[j - 2] - 1] = info[j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
А вот алгоритм

while (!versh.empty())
    {
        int temp;
        temp = versh.front();
        versh.pop();
        for (int l = 0; l < N; l++)
        {
            int m = 1, b = 1;
            if (ves[temp][l] >= 0)
            {
                if (temp != 0)
                {
                    if (redcolor[temp] != -1)
                    {
                        if (cvet[temp][l] == 1)
                        {
                            blackcolor[l] = cvet[temp][l];
                            m = 2;
                        }
                        if (tcvet[temp][l] == 1)
                        {
                            blackcolor[l] = tcvet[temp][l];
                            b = 2;
                        }
                    }//цвет вершины в которую пришёл по красному чёрный
                    if (blackcolor[temp] != -1)
                    {
                        if (cvet[temp][l] == 0)
                        {
                            redcolor[l] = cvet[temp][l];
                            m = 3;
                        }
                        if (tcvet[temp][l] == 0)
                        {
                            redcolor[l] = tcvet[temp][l];
                            b = 3;
                        }
                    }//аналогично только красный
                }
                else
                {
                    if (cvet[temp][l] == 0)
                    {
                        redcolor[l] = 0;
                        m = 3;
                    }
                    if (tcvet[temp][l] == 1)
                    {
                        blackcolor[l] = 1;
                        b = 2;
                    }
                    if (cvet[temp][l] == 1)
                    {
                        blackcolor[l] = 1;
                        m = 2;
                    }
                    if (tcvet[temp][l] == 0)
                    {
                        redcolor[l] = 0;
                        b = 3;
                    }
                }
                if ((redcolor[l] != -1) && (m == 3 || b == 3))
                {
                    if (m == 3)
                    {
                        if (reddist[l] > blackdist[temp] + ves[temp][l])
                        {
                            reddist[l] = blackdist[temp] + ves[temp][l];
                            versh.push(l);
                        }
                    }
                    if (b == 3)
                    {
                        if (reddist[l] > blackdist[temp] + tves[temp][l])
                        {
                            reddist[l] = blackdist[temp] + tves[temp][l];
                            versh.push(l);
                        }

                    }
                }
                if ((blackcolor[l] != -1) && (m == 2 || b == 2))
                {
                    if (m == 2)
                    {
                        if (blackdist[l] > reddist[temp] + ves[temp][l])
                        {
                            blackdist[l] = reddist[temp] + ves[temp][l];
                            versh.push(l);
                        }
                    }
                    if (b == 2)
                    {
                        if (blackdist[l] > reddist[temp] + tves[temp][l])
                        {
                            blackdist[l] = reddist[temp] + tves[temp][l];
                            versh.push(l);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            m = 1;
            b = 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен алгоритм Дейкстры (Dijkstra) с небольшим дополнением. Усложнение алгоритма в том, как обрабатывать повторный приход в вершину по ребру "другого" цвета. Получается в вершине надо хранить пару путей (весов) - по черному и по красному "приходу", и дальнейший путь строить отталкиваясь от них.

Если пришли по "тому же" цвету, то просто заменяете значение на лучшее.

Какую же информацию хранить в вершине?

- красную вершину из которой пришли
- накопленный красный "вес"
- черную вершину из которой пришли
- накопленный черный "вес"

Comment: Понимаю,что Дейкстры,но дело в том,что если я в эту вершину пришёл двумя путями(красным и чёрным), то из неё я могу пойти дальше в любую вершину. И это реализовано,но не проходит тесты

Comment: Что-то ощущение, что может и не сработать - попадаем в какую-то вершину, скажем, по черному ребру, а там уже есть меньший путь по красному. Но мы не можем при этом отбрасывать наш черный путь, потому как непонятно, что будет дальше при пути из этой вершины... Мне кажется, стоит рассматривать отдельно все пути, начинающиеся с красного ребра, и отдельно - пути, начинающиеся с черного, а потом сравнивать минимальные... Это открытая система, где вы тестируете? В смысле, посторонним можно лезть? Если да - не дадите URL?

Comment: Так а как вот сохранять эти цвета? Например,есть вершина, я в неё пришёл по красному и по чёрному ребру и эта вершина соединена с ещё 4 вершинами. Так как я в эту вершину прихожу двумя различными способами,то я могу пойти дальше в любую из этих 4. Но как это сделать?

Comment: Нет,система,к сожалению,закрытая. Но если вам интересно,то могу дать аккаунт

Comment: @Harry спасибо что натолкнули на мысль! Сейчас, кажется, все учтено.

Comment: Попробую сейчас реализовать

Comment: @Артём если не получится - дополните вопрос кодом (только уберите из него все лишнее, чтобы небыло "простыни")

Comment: Я вас понял,хорошо

Comment: Да нет, если у вас получится - то не надо. Просто я в идее на 150% не уверен, хотел потестировать :)

Comment: как-то у меня снова получилось не очень,поэтому прикрепляю код к задаче